# Как найти все нужные символы из динамических библиотек на старте?

Tags: c, linux, оптимизация

Доброго времени суток, коллеги!

У меня есть демон, работающий под Linux, который форкается на каждый коннект. Профилировка показала, что большое потребление процессора происходит в функции "do_lookup_x". Я так понимаю, из-за того, что работа с библиотеками осуществляется после форка, то на каждый коннект приходится подгружать символы из библиотек.

Можно ли как-то загрузить все нужные символы до форка?

Comment: Если проблема в этом, вы явно форкаетесь слишком часто. Попробуйте использовать треды (в Linux они от форков отличаются только общим адресным пространством с родителем). Кроме того, использование процессора в сетевом демоне не должно быть основной целью профилирования, потому что узкое место там обычно - network I/O

Comment: Это огромный Legacy проект. К тому же весьма нагруженный. Переписание на треды будет невероятно сложным, потому что проект - одна большая глобальная переменная.

Comment: Еще как вариант - сделать пул воркеров, передавать им задачи через IPC.